# C# multiplayer server

Tags: c#, php, sockets, server, multiplayer

I am trying to create a server based game using Unity, but I do not know how to do some things.
I spoke with a teacher of my school and he said that i need a domain that will host the server, and that is possible also using free hosting services like altervista. but I do not know how to interface a C# application with a server on a domain, and also how to create this server. 
at the moment i am only trying to set a connection between two client and, when a client is connected, a player spawn in the scene, where it can be moved and it move also on other client, and i have done with local connection. i think i have to use socket, but i don't know how to use it to do it.
so the questions are: 
how can I create a server with PHP that will run on a domain and make it interfacing two client? the server only has to recive position (int x,int y) of the player, and send it to other players connected.
and how can i let a client request data to the server continuosly to see other players new position?

excuse me if the question is not clear, or if i have done errors in formuling my question.

Comment: I don't think PHP is a very good platform for implementing a real-time game server, *especially* if it's running under some web server. You'll need to get a server where you can run an actual server program that you write (perhaps in C#).

Comment: Do you know also where to get a server with few €/$? I am a student at 5th year of technical instutute and i am developing this as project for my diploma so i don't have so many money.
anyway, if i get a server, could you tell me what type of server is suitable for this? and how could i run a program on that server?

Comment: If it's just for a school project, do you need a permanent server? You could just run on on any computer when needed. If you want a permanent one you can get a VPS for a very modest price, google around for reviews. Just n.b. if you need to run Windows software on them that'll usually set you back more because Windows isn't free.

Comment: yes it is for a schoolproject but i am planning to publish it. currently i could run it on a computer, but I don't have static and public IP. is it possible to connect remote player also with private dynamic IP?

Comment: There are free dynamic DNS services that can provide a name for a dynamic IP. If it's private and behind NAT you will have to set up port forwarding.

Comment: I think you may have bitten off a bit more than you can chew at the moment. For a game server, it will likely communicate over TCP / UDP with some custom game server software. You'll need an entire VPS, as well as serving hosting software that must be able to know how the game client communicates, as well as what kind of meaningful data to return. Of course, this is oversimplified, and there's alot more to it, but I would suggest reading up on the prebuilt unity implementations of multiplayer.

Comment: yes it is behind a NAT, it's XAMPP enough to set port forwarding ? or how i do it?

Comment: XAMPP has nothing to do with NAT or port forwarding.

Comment: yes i know it. i took a look to unity implementations but most of it is for local connection, or commands and implementation are the same? i have done it using localhost as IP and 25000 as port

Comment: okay so i will look for port forwarding.

Comment: PHP is a pretty terrible choice for something like this. It's not impossible, but why the hell would you choose PHP when you can run any language on a linux VPS. Any language that has sockets can do what you want, you don't need a website for this. Just choose whatever you're more confident with (java c c++ python c#) and write an application that listens to sockets, processes the data and sends the processed data to both sockets. Also use UDP, you don't want your server hanging if one of the clients hangs.

Comment: ok thanks. do you even know if procedure to setup a local connection and  connection with VPS are similar?